# Are there any Python libraries to convert a sentence in hiragana to kanji?

Tags: nlp

If I have a phrase or sentence written in Hiragana such as 「おふろはいる」 I would like to translate/guess at the appropriate Kanji for the string.

I have found libraries for going from Kanji to Hiragana, Katakana, Romaji, or English, but I haven't found ones that go the other way. Dictionaries work fine for single words but not sentences.

Answer (score 1):

Original post (see below): I don't think so, because going from a sentence of hiragana to kanji really requires parsing the language and meaning of the entire phrase as opposed to just doing something like character lookups. For parsing the entire language you really need something like the full force of google translate. One approach to get something functional-ish could be to programmatically use google translate's api (or another online translation tool), that uses advanced algorithms to interpret the full meaning of the sentence which would then automatically choose the appropriate kanji.

If your sentence uses spaces to delineate words on the other hand, you might have luck with something similar to the libraries you noted. Jisho.org might have a publicly facing api in that case.

Edit: I didn't get it to work yet, but I think you may have luck using this google translate api python package (https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans). There's currently a bug (https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/286) so if you test it, use `pip3 install googletrans==3.1.0a0` to get a working version.

The goal is to basically parse the result of "did you mean?"
[image]

Edit 2: Aha I knew it was hiding in there somewhere. It's buried but we can dig it out. It works from romaji, so if you convert to romaji then do the following then you can get what you want.

```py
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()

res = translator.translate('ofurohairu')

res.extra_data['translation'][0][1]
#Output: 'お風呂はいる'

# This apparently also works for hiragana:
res = translator.translate('おふろはいる')

res.extra_data['translation'][0][1]
#Output: 'お風呂はいる'
```

Comment: Note that this API might not be stable in the long term. According to the github page (https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans), "You may wonder why this library works properly, whereas other approaches such like goslate won't work since Google has updated its translation service recently with a ticket mechanism to prevent a lot of crawler programs.

I eventually figure out a way to generate a ticket by reverse engineering on the obfuscated and minified code used by Google to generate such token, and implemented on the top of Python. However, this could be blocked at any time."